# Correct way to configure similar prefixes for 2 A records / servers in BIND file?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

My domain provider's config tool doesn't seem to support what I'm trying to do and I'm unsure of the proper BIND syntax for the below - any pointers appreciated!

I've got separate physical production servers and staging servers and I'd like domain.org to point to production, and staging.domain.org to point to the staging server + have m/www/api prefixes for each server.

Here's what I think I need in my zone file for domain.org:

```
@ 10800 IN A $production-IP
staging 10800 IN A $staging-IP
api 10800 IN CNAME domain.org
api 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
m 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
m 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
www 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
www 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
```

But I wonder if that's still ambiguous for BIND or if these are just a bunch of duplicate records?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All names that do not end with `.` are qualified by the current domain setting. If that's `domain.org` your proposed configuration will look like this:

```
domain.org 10800 IN A $production-IP
staging.domain.org 10800 IN A $staging-IP
api.domain.org 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.domain.org.
api.domain.org 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
m.domain.org 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
m.domain.org 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
www.domain.org 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
www.domain.org 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
```

I suspect that's not what you want. You can try either of these instead, but neither will really save you very much:

Option 1

```
domain.org 10800 IN A $production-IP
staging.domain.org 10800 IN A $staging-IP
api 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
m 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
www 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
api.staging 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
m.staging 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
www.staging 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
```

Option 2

```
$ORIGIN domain.org.
@ 10800 IN A $production-IP
api 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
m 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
www 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.

$ORIGIN staging.domain.org.
@ 10800 IN A $staging-IP
api 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
m 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
www 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your syntax is incorrect.... this is the right syntax:

```
@ 10800 IN A $production-IP
staging 10800 IN A $staging-IP
api 10800 IN CNAME domain.org
api.staging 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
m 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
m.staging 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
www 10800 IN CNAME domain.org.
www.staging 10800 IN CNAME staging.domain.org.
```

(your can see that you defined api, m, and www twice pointing to different places... when you read these syntax, api by itself --and not dot after it, really reads api.mydomain.org... when you have api.staging --not dot at the end, what you are "saying" is api.staging.mydomain.org.)

Also... your TTL is 3 hours (10800... seconds;) in the "old times" that was OK... in my dns servers  I use no more than 30 minutes, with not a terrible load on the server :)

Cheers!

Marcos

Answer (score 0):

You need different left-hand-side labels to support the prefixed names for production and staging.  As written there's no way to distinguish `m` etc between the two, because you've created two entries for `m.domain.org`, etc.

The simplest method is to use the `$ORIGIN` directive twice, combined with `@` to reference the current origin:

```
$TTL 10800        ; to avoid repetition
$ORIGIN domain.org.
@   IN A $production-IP
api IN CNAME @
m   IN CNAME @
www IN CNAME @

$ORIGIN staging   ; NB - implicitly adds current $ORIGIN
@   IN A $staging-IP
api IN CNAME @
m   IN CNAME @
www IN CNAME @
```